# Making a stacked bar plot for multiple variables - ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some problems with making a stacked bar chart in ggplot2. I know how to make one with barplot(), but I wanted to use ggplot2 because it's very easy to make the bars have the same height (with 'position = 'fill'', if I'm not mistaken).

My problem is that I have multiple variables that I want to plot on top of each other; my data looks like this:

```
dfr <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
  V2 = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.2),
  V3 = c(0.3, 0.6, 0.5),
  V4 = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.7),
  row.names = LETTERS[1:3]
)
```

What I want is a plot with categories A, B, and C on the X axis, and for each of those, the values for V1, V2, V3, and V4 stacked on top of each other on the Y axis. Most graphs that I have seen plot only one variable on the Y axis, but I'm sure that one could do this somehow.

How could I do this with ggplot2? Thanks!

Comment: +1 for adding sample data.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful, please select one as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, some data manipulation.  Add the category as a variable and melt the data to long format.

```
dfr$category <- row.names(dfr)
mdfr <- melt(dfr, id.vars = "category")
```

Now plot, using the variable named `variable` to determine the fill colour of each bar.

```
library(scales)
(p <- ggplot(mdfr, aes(category, value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
)
```

(EDIT: Code updated to use `scales` packages, as required since ggplot2 v0.9.)

[image]

Comment: @lselzer, great minds think alike! IMO, next time, you should not hesitate to post your answer, even if very similar.

Comment: Thanks so much Richie! This works for me. I have one question though - if I plot it with 'p <- ggplot(mdfr, aes(category, value, fill = variable, position = 'fill')) +
+   geom_bar()'; the bars do not extend upwards to have the same height. Do I need to do any thing else in order for the plot to do that? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me... I am getting Error in continuous_scale(c("y", "ymin", "ymax", "yend", "yintercept",  : 
  unused argument(s) (formatter = "percent")

Comment: @RachitAgrawal, I think you must update the code. Use library(scales) and then change the code above: scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)

Comment: New ``ggplot`` syntax apparently requires ``geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") ``

Answer (score 4):

Excuse me for initiating a new answer while I really just want to add a comment on the beautiful solution provided by @Richie. I don't have the minimal points to post a comments, so here is my case:

The `... + geom_bar(position="fill")` threw an error for my plotting, I'm using ggplot2 version 0.9.3.1. and reshape2 rather than reshape for the melting.

```
error_message:
*Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin".
  With stat="bin", it will attempt to set the y value to the count of cases in each group.
  This can result in unexpected behavior and will not be allowed in a future version of ggplot2.
  If you want y to represent counts of cases, use stat="bin" and don't map a variable to y.
  If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".
  See ?geom_bar for examples. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.2)
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
Error in pmin(y, 0) : object 'y' not found*
```

So I changed it to `geom_bar(stat='identity')` and it works.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, I couldn't figure out how to fix this error!

Answer (score 4):

You could also do like this

```
library(tidyverse)
dfr %>% rownames_to_column("ID") %>% pivot_longer(!ID) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = ID, y = value, fill = name), position = 'fill')
```

[image]