# plotting the given color for horizontal bar graph and coloring the unplotted area with grey using ggplot2

Tags: r

I have the dataset `Global`as below;

```
Win.Rate    Perc    bar.color
0-25         11%    Green
25-50         8%    Red
50-75        47%    Yellow
75-100       86%    Green
```

First, I want the bar chart color to be the corresponding color from the `bar.color` column.

Second, I would like to add a grey color to the bar plot after the given values is plotted.

Say for example, after the 11% is plotted with Green color on the bar chart for the remaining area I would want it to be colored in Grey.

based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077511/adding-a-different-color-to-the-barplot-using-ggplot2-in-r)

I tried the below code

```
   Global$diff = 100 -   
             as.numeric(substr(Global$Perc,0,nchar(Global$Perc)-1))
   library(reshape)
   melt_data <- melt(Global,id="Win.Rate")
```

But I am getting an error saying:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Answer (score 0):

To get to your desired plot, you do not need to use `melt`. But to answer your most direct question, the reason why you are getting an error is because you are trying to stack all of `Perc`, `bar.color`, `diff` into a single column called `value`. `Perc` and `bar.color` are likely `factor`, and `diff` is a `numeric`, which causes problems because a column can only have one type, and `melt` is having a hard time figuring out which one it is that you want.

But here is a solution to what you want:

```
# Read in data
Global <- read.table(textConnection("Win.Rate    Perc    bar.color
0-25         11%    Green
25-50         8%    Red
50-75        47%    Yellow
75-100       86%    Green"), header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
# A cleaner version of your diff
Global$percentage <- as.numeric(gsub('%','',Global$Perc))
ggplot(Global, aes(x=Win.Rate, y=percentage)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="grey", aes(y=100)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=Global$bar.color) +
  coord_flip() + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @ nograpes this is what i really wanted. and it helped me.

Comment: If you like it, you can click the check box to the left of the question.