# How to make a stacked barplot with nested grouping variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to make a stacked barplot with two variables. My desired outcome looks like this:

[image: this]

This is the first part of my data. There are 220 more rows:

```
      Type      Week Stage
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Captured     1     2
 2 Captured     1     1
 3 Captured     1     1
 4 Captured     1     2
 5 Captured     1     1
 6 Captured     1     3
 7 Captured     1    NA
 8 Captured     1     3
 9 Captured     1     2
10 Captured     1     1
```

So far I'm not getting anywhere, this is my code so far

```
library(data.table)
dat.m <- melt(newrstudio2, id.vars="Type")
dat.m

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=Type, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I guess I need to calculate the number of observations of each stage in each week of each type? I've tried both long and wide data, but I somehow need to combine week with type? I don't know, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693257/making-a-stacked-bar-plot-for-multiple-variables-ggplot2-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative way:

```
set.seed(123)
# sample data
my_data <- data.frame(Type = sample(c("W", "C"), 220, replace = TRUE),
                      Week = sample(paste0("Week ", 1:4), 220, replace = TRUE),
                      Stage = sample(paste0('S', 1:4), 220, replace = TRUE))
head(my_data)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Type, fill = Stage)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), position = "fill") +
  facet_grid(. ~ Week, switch="both") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  ylab("Stage [%]") + 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: Great to hear that. Could you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively we could use base graphics. First, what you're probably most interested in, we should reshape the data.

For this we could split the data per week and run a `dcast()` over it.

```
L <- lapply(split(d, d$week), function(x) 
  data.table::dcast(x, type ~ stage, value.var="stage", fun=length))

d2 <- do.call(rbind, L)  # transform back into a data frame
```

Now – [*with credits to @alemol*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12748784/6574038) – we want the proportions.

```
d2[-1] <- t(apply(d2[-1], 1, prop.table))
```

Then we are able to plot relatively simply. Note, that `barplot()` additionally gives us a vector of bar coordinates which we can use later for the `axis()` labels.

```
cols <- c("#ed1c24", "#ff7f27", "#00a2e8", "#fff200")  # define stage colors

par(mar=c(5, 5, 3, 5) + .1, xpd=TRUE)  # set plot margins

p <- barplot(t(d2[-1]), col=cols, border="white", space=rep(c(.2, 0), 5), 
        font.axis=2, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="Week")
axis(1, at=p, labels=rep(c("C", "W"), 5), tick=FALSE, line=0)
axis(1, at=apply(matrix(p, , 2, byrow=TRUE), 1, mean), labels=1:5, tick=FALSE, line=1)
axis(2, at=0:10/10, labels=paste0(seq(0, 100, 10), "%"), line=0, las=2)
legend(12, .5, legend=rev(names(d2[-1])), col=rev(cols), pch=15, title="Stage")
```

***Result:***

[image]

---

***Data:***

```
d <- structure(list(type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("C", "W"), class = "factor"), week = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), stage = c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -250L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
set.seed(123)
# sample data
my_data <- data.frame(Type = sample(paste0('T', 1:4), 220, replace = TRUE),
                      Week = sample(paste0('W', 1:4), 220, replace = TRUE),
                      Stage = sample(paste0('S', 1:4), 220, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(my_data, aes(x=Week:Type, fill = Stage)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me, got the warning message "Error in Type:Week: NA/NaN argument. Numerical expression has 225 elements: only the first used."  Omitted NA, but still no luck. The other solution worked.