# An issue when ploting geom bar with multiple varaibels

Tags: r

I have the following data:

[image]

I would like to generate a bar plot that shows the frequency of each value of `Var1` per each run. I want the x axis represents each run and the y axis represents the frequency of each `Var1` value. To do that, I wrote the following R script:

```
df <- read.csv("/home/nasser/Desktop/data.csv")
g <- ggplot(df) +  
    geom_bar(aes(Run, Freq, fill = Var1, colour = Var1), position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```

The result that I got is:

[image]

The issue is that the x axis does not show each run seperately (the axis should be 1, 2, .., etc) and the legend should show each value of `Var1` seperately and in a different color. Also, the bars are not so clear since it is so difficult to see the frequency of each `Var1` values. In other words, the generated plot is not the normal stacked bar like the one shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693427/1046657)

How to solve that?

Comment: don't share data as image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Convert run to factor with `factor(Run)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert both variables to factors. Otherwise, R sees them as numerical and not categorical data.

```
df <- read.csv("/home/nasser/Desktop/data.csv")
g <- ggplot(df) +  
    geom_bar(aes(factor(Run), Freq, fill = factor(Var1), colour = factor(Var1)), 
             position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```